# Dynamics CRM Language Pack

Tags: dynamics-crm

Does anybody knows how to develope a new language pack for Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to just translate your CRM? take a look here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/export-customized-entity-and-field-text-for-translation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to know how to develop a complete new language pack (like the ones you could download here ['Language Pack Downloads'](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=50761e58-6040-4cf3-853a-f5ab535f7194&displayLang=en)

Sadly, there is no supported/documented way to build own language packs. However if you are interested in how to translate your own entities then take a look at ['Support for Multiple Languages'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151170.aspx)